# Hosting a Website using Google Drive/Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am in the early stages of modifying a Bootstrap theme for a personal website. When I host the site on google drive, however, the smooth scrolling feature of the website does not work.

When I load the site locally I have no issues. Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this effect to work?

Here is the theme that I am modifying:    http://startbootstrap.com/templates/freelancer/

Here is my site hosted by google drive:

https://www.googledrive.com/host/0BxvBp_ipgmHvY3h1WmhfS1c0S1E/#page-top

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478447/google-drive-hosted-css-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the dev console in your browser you'll see an error message like this:
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.googledrive.com/host/0BxvBp_ipgmHvY3h1WmhfS1c0S1E/#page-top' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS

So, switch the reference to the easing library from 'http://' to 'httpS://'

Answer (score 0):

You may also use dedicated Bootstrap hosting - http://www.bootstrap.hosting/